# Parse an XML fragment stored in a string into nodes in XSLT with SAXON for Java

Tags: xml, xslt, saxon

In my XSLT, I have a variable which contains a string.  This string contains a fragment of XML. This is coming in programmatically, but its the equivalent of this:

```
<xsl:variable name="xmlfrag" select="'<foo>this <bar>is</bar> it</foo>'"/>
```

Is there a way to parse this XML and add it to the output? We're using SAXON for Java.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete and easy solution. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use the [`saxon:parse()`](http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/extensions/functions/parse.xml) extension function**.

Answer (score 1):

The Dimitre solution requires a licensed version of Saxon.

Here is another solution that works also with the free version of Saxon.

I've tried it successfully with Saxon HE 9.5.X.

The inverse process is [documented here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6696382/xslt-how-to-convert-xml-node-to-string/24507312#24507312).

It is about [registering a custom extension function](http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/index.html#!extensibility/integratedfunctions/ext-full-J) with these contents:

```
import net.sf.saxon.expr.XPathContext;
import net.sf.saxon.lib.ExtensionFunctionCall;
import net.sf.saxon.lib.ExtensionFunctionDefinition;
import net.sf.saxon.om.Sequence;
import net.sf.saxon.om.StructuredQName;
import net.sf.saxon.s9api.DocumentBuilder;
import net.sf.saxon.s9api.Processor;
import net.sf.saxon.s9api.SaxonApiException;
import net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException;
import net.sf.saxon.value.SequenceType;

import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

import java.io.StringReader;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class XmlParser extends ExtensionFunctionDefinition {
    @Override
    public StructuredQName getFunctionQName() {
        return new StructuredQName("vis", URI, "my.custom.uri");
    }

    @Override
    public SequenceType[] getArgumentTypes() {
        return new SequenceType[] { SequenceType.SINGLE_STRING };
    }

    @Override
    public SequenceType getResultType(SequenceType[] sequenceTypes) {
        return SequenceType.NODE_SEQUENCE;
    }

    @Override
    public ExtensionFunctionCall makeCallExpression() {
        return new ExtensionFunctionCall() {
            DocumentBuilder constructor;

            @Override
            public Sequence call(XPathContext ctx, Sequence[] secs) throws XPathException {
                // Not synchronized, as worst case it initialize twice
                if (constructor == null)
                    constructor = new Processor(ctx.getConfiguration()).newDocumentBuilder();
                String xml = secs[0].head().getStringValue();
                try {
                    return constructor.build(new StreamSource(new StringReader(xml))).getUnderlyingNode();
                } catch (SaxonApiException e) {
                    final int max = 500;
                    String xml2 = xml.length() > 500 ? xml.substring(0, max)+"..." : xml;
                    throw new XPathException("Error when parsing XML.\n"+xml2, e);
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

You can use this function as follows:

```
<xs:value-of xmlns:vis="my.custom.uri" select="vis:parse-xml('<a>Test</a>')"/>
```