# Spilt a XML in CDATA into multiple chunks using XSL

Tags: xml, xslt, cdata, ibm-datapower

I have a requirement where I have to insert the SOAP Messages into a DB where the Message field character length is say 200 characters.
I have to use XSLT to acheive this and I am getting the SoapMessage in a CDATA section.

Below is the SOAP Message that I store in a variable within a CDATA Tag

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:v4="http://www.example.com/ServiceBody/V4">
  <soapenv:Header>
  </soapenv:Header>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <v4:getBookDetails>
      <v4:Request>
        <catalog>
          <book id="bk101">
            <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
            <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
            <genre>Computer</genre>
            <price>44.95</price>
            <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
            <description>An in-depth look at creating applications with XML.</description>
          </book>
        </catalog>
      </v4:Request>
    </v4:getBookDetails>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Below is the XSLT that I have written to get the message into multiple tags so that I can insert it into the DB.

```
<xsl:stylesheet extension-element-prefixes="date str" exclude-result-prefixes="dp str date" version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:date="http://exslt.org/dates-and-times" xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings">
    <xsl:output method="xml"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="cdataVariable">   
            <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;![CDATA[</xsl:text>
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">]]&gt;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:variable>
        <MessageInChunks>
            <stringLength><xsl:value-of select="string-length($cdataVariable)"/></stringLength>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="string-length($cdataVariable) &lt; 200">
                    <Chunks>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="$cdataVariable"/>  
                    </Chunks>           
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:call-template name="splitMessageIntoChunks">
                        <xsl:with-param name="messageToSplit">
                        <xsl:copy-of select="$cdataVariable"/>
                        </xsl:with-param>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </MessageInChunks>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="splitMessageIntoChunks">
        <xsl:param name="messageToSplit"/>
        <xsl:variable name="chunkSize" select="'200'"/>
        <xsl:if test="string-length($messageToSplit) >0">
            <Chunks>
                <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;![CDATA[</xsl:text>
                <xsl:copy-of select="substring($messageToSplit, 12, $chunkSize)"/>
                <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">]]&gt;</xsl:text>
            </Chunks>
            <xsl:call-template name="splitMessageIntoChunks">
                <xsl:with-param name="messageToSplit" select="substring($messageToSplit, $chunkSize+1)"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But the output that I am getting doesnt contain the elements expect for the values as the output of the substring function is not displaying the elements.

I need something like this.

```
<MessageInChunks>
<Chunks>&lt;![CDATA[<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:v4="http://www.example.com/ServiceBody/V4">
  <soapenv:Header>
  </soapenv:Header>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <v4:getBookDet]]&gt;</Chunks>
<Chunks>&lt;![CDATA[ails>
      <v4:Request>
        <catalog>
          <book id="bk101">
            <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
            <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
            <genre>Compu]]&gt;
</Chunks>
<Chunks>&lt;![CDATA[ter</genre>
            <price>44.95</price>
            <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
            <description>An in-depth look at creating applications with XML.</description>
        ]]&gt;
</Chunks>
<Chunks>&lt;![CDATA[  </book>
        </catalog>
      </v4:Request>
    </v4:getBookDetails>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>]]&gt;
</Chunks>
</MessageInChunks>
```

Basically what I need is to spilt a XML message into chunks of 200 characters and get it into a CDATA section using XSLT.

Kindly help me with this issue.

Comment: Since you got the logic to split the data into chunks of 200 characters right, this is basically a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6696382/xslt-how-to-convert-xml-node-to-string.

Comment: @AndreasVeithen..Converting the input XML into a string is not helpful in my scenario as this message has to be reconverted into XML before it is displayed in another tool. Since I am using Data Power, I used dp:serialize as suggested in one of the answer and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you have your question tagged with `ibm-datapower`.  Are you running this XSLT on a DataPower appliance?  If so, you really should look into the DataPower extension element `dp:serialize`, which will make your life much easier.

Take a look here: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS9H2Y_6.0.1/com.ibm.dp.xi.doc/serialize_element.html

Comment: Thanks bjimba.. dp:serialize works in this case. I had to remove the CDATA section and just serialize the SOAP message and voila... everything works... :)

Comment: Glad to hear it. Could you please accept this answer, so others will know about it?

Answer (score 0):

I think, first of all, you have to get rid of the XML tags in order to treat everything as a string and split it up.

I'd suggest doing something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml"/>
    <xsl:template match="*"> <!-- GET rid of XML tags by replacing them with escaped chars -->
        &lt;<xsl:value-of select="name()"/><xsl:for-each select="@*"><xsl:text> </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="name()"/>="<xsl:value-of select="."/>"</xsl:for-each>&gt;<xsl:apply-templates/>&lt;/<xsl:value-of select="name()"/>&gt;
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="everything_in_one_string"><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:variable> <!-- Put complete output in one variable -->

        <xsl:variable name="everything_in_one_string_normalized" as="xs:string" select="normalize-space($everything_in_one_string)"/> <!-- Get rid of whitespace -->

        <xsl:variable name="string_length_of_total" as="xs:integer" select="string-length($everything_in_one_string_normalized)"/>

        <xsl:variable name="max_string_length_of_substrings" as="xs:integer" select="200"/>

        <xsl:variable name="runs_necessary" as="xs:integer" select="ceiling($string_length_of_total div $max_string_length_of_substrings) cast as xs:integer"/>
                                                                      <!-- Compute how many chunks of 200 chars we need. -->

        <MessageInChunks>
        <xsl:for-each select="1 to $runs_necessary">
            <xsl:variable name="current_run" as="xs:integer" select="."/>
            <Chunks><xsl:value-of select="substring($everything_in_one_string_normalized,((($current_run - 1)* $max_string_length_of_substrings) + 1),200)"/></Chunks>
            <!-- Always extract 200 chars from the string.
            For the first run: Start at 1: ((1 - 1) * 200) + 1 = 0 * 200 + 1 = 1
            Second run: ((2 - 1) * 200) + 1 = 1 * 200 + 1 = 201
            and so on
            -->
        </xsl:for-each>
        </MessageInChunks>

    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This solution is not entirely correct because it doesn't serialize namespace declarations and character references are not correctly escaped. If the OP needs a solution for logging purposes only, that may be OK, but not if there is a requirement to be able to reconstruct the SOAP message later.

Comment: @cis. I wont be able to use this as i need to reproduce the SOAP message as-is on another monitoring tool and I cannot tamper with the message.