# XSLT - XML into CDATA

Tags: xml, xslt, mule, cdata

I have a `mule flow` that transforms a `XML`:

`HTTP Listener > Logger > XSLT > Logger`

This is the **original message**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope/" xmlns:pref="URI_SOAP_WS">
   <soap:Body>
      <entryXML>
         <note>
            <to>Totest</to>
            <from>Fromtest</from>
            <heading>Query</heading>
            <body>Update Windows 10</body>
         </note>
      </entryXML>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I want to transform with `XSLT` to this:

```
<entryXML>
   &lt;note&gt;
    &lt;to&gt;Totest&lt;/to&gt;
    &lt;from&gt;Fromtest&lt;/from&gt;
    &lt;heading&gt;Query&lt;/heading&gt;
    &lt;body&gt;Update Windows 10&lt;/body&gt;
    &lt;/note&gt;
<entryXML>
```

I tried with this **template**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:pref="URI_SOAP_WS">

    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"
        indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:value-of select="serialize(.)" />
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But it transform from `<entryXML>` to `</soap:Envolve>`.

How can I transform **only the content** of `<entryXML></entryXML>`?

Comment: Did you review this question and answers? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6696382/xslt-how-to-convert-xml-node-to-string ... your issue I would believe is that you are using a 1.0 stylesheet and trying to use the serialze() function which is 3.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following solution is based on [the answer by jelovirt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6698849/1987598) that [Kevin Brown has linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35586057/xslt-xml-into-cdata/35587000#comment58858749_35586057). You could use the XSLT 3.0 (XPath 3.0) [`serialize`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-30/#func-serialize) function or the Saxon extension function that is called [`saxon:serialize`](http://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/functions/fn/serialize.html), but the solution below is more portable because it works with XSLT 1.0.

Start with an identity template to copy everything that is not matched by a more specific template. In your example, this would match the outer SOAP elements.

Then match the `entryXML` element as the starting point of the special serialization mode. Any content inside `entryXML` will be processed in a mode other than the default, and only templates with this mode can be matched against the input.

**XSLT Stylesheet**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="entryXML">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:variable name="nodestring">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" mode="serialize"/>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:value-of select="$nodestring"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*" mode="serialize">
        <xsl:text>&lt;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
        <xsl:text>&gt;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates mode="serialize"/>
        <xsl:text>&lt;/</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
        <xsl:text>&gt;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()" mode="serialize">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

**XML Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope/"
               xmlns:pref="URI_SOAP_WS"
               xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/">
   <soap:Body>
      <entryXML>
         &lt;note&gt;
            &lt;to&gt;Tove&lt;/to&gt;
            &lt;from&gt;Jani&lt;/from&gt;
            &lt;heading&gt;Reminder&lt;/heading&gt;
            &lt;body&gt;Don't forget me this weekend!&lt;/body&gt;
         &lt;/note&gt;
      </entryXML>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

---

**EDIT 1**

The approach above does not serialize attributes in the message, if there are any. If you also need to preserve attributes, e.g. in a message like

```
<entryXML>
     <note>
        <to with="love">Tove</to>
            ^^^^^^^^^^^               attribute
```

you would need to add a template along the lines of

```
<xsl:template match="@*" mode="serialize">
    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
    <xsl:text>="</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```

and also change the template that matches `*` in the `serialize` mode:

```
<xsl:template match="*" mode="serialize">
  <xsl:text>&lt;</xsl:text>
  <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" mode="serialize"/>
  <xsl:text>&gt;</xsl:text>
  <xsl:apply-templates mode="serialize"/>
  <xsl:text>&lt;/</xsl:text>
  <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
  <xsl:text>&gt;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```

---

**EDIT 2**

Caution: The solution above is XSLT 1.0 only, but it also has shortcomings and there is no guarantee that it will serialize correctly in every possible case.

It works in a simple case like yours, but robust, general serialization "requires more effort", as Martin Honnen has put it. See e.g. [Evan Lenz's stylesheet](http://lenzconsulting.com/xml-to-string/) for a more sophisticated approach.

Alternatively, you can modify your original XSLT 3.0 stylesheet to (borrowing some of the ideas above)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="entryXML/*">
            <xsl:value-of select="serialize(.)" />
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

which will also lead to a more reliable serialization.

Comment: Thanks, it works fine ! But I don't understand the last answer. About, the XML message, the information was different, I've just edited to prevent confusions.

Comment: @mikedev What do you mean by the last answer? My addition about attributes?

Comment: While obviously an XSLT 1.0 solution is nice, however, I think you should really point out the shortcomings of the few templates, like lack of proper escaping of characters like the ampersand or the less than sign, for instance, to start with. I am afraid, proper XML serialization requires more effort, see http://lenzconsulting.com/xml-to-string/.

Comment: @MartinHonnen I will add a note about that, too. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @MartinHonnen I have edited my answer. Please let me know if you agree.