# XSLT convert inner xml to attribute

Tags: xml, xslt

Let's say I've got the following XML:

```
<a>
    <c>
       <d>text</d><e> more text</e>
    </c>
</a>
```

And I'd like to get:

```
<a>
    <d innerXML="&lt;d&gt;text&lt;/d&gt;&lt;e&gt; more text&lt;/e&gt;">
    </d>
</a>
```

How would I select the inner XML of `c`? The following XSLT doesn't work:

```
<xsl:template match="c">
   <d>
      <xsl:attribute name="innerXML">
         <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
      </xsl:attribute>
   </d>
</xsl:template>
```

P.S. Please note that this is an *extremely* simplified version of what I'm try

Comment: have a look at this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6696382/xslt-how-to-convert-xml-node-to-string

Comment: You want to serialize the sub-tree; this feature is available in XSLT 3.0 (and in some XSLT 2.0 processors as an extension). Doing this natively in XSLT 1.0 or 2.0 is very awkward and error-prone.

Comment: Can you use a programming language like c# for this goal?