# XSLT/XPath: Treat <tag> as ordinary string, not node

Tags: xslt, xpath

I have an XML:

```
<foo>
    <bar>some text</bar>
</foo>
```

And I'm generating an HTML from it using XSTL, and looking for an Xpath (or some XSTL method, don't know) that gives me the whole content of foo. To illustrate my problem,

```
<xsl:value-of select="foo"/>
```

as expected, delivers only

```
some text
```

. But is there anything I can do to get

```
<bar>some text</bar>
```

? So to treat it as if the bar tags would be just ordinary strings.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XSLT: How to convert XML Node to String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6696382/xslt-how-to-convert-xml-node-to-string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there's certainly no way of treating `<tag>` as a string, because XSLT sees the output of the XML parser, which is a tree of nodes: the tags have long since disappeared by the time XSLT swings into action.

But you can of course copy the element node as a whole, rather than just extracting its string value. Simply use `<xsl:copy-of>` in place of `<xsl:value-of>`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Copy`

**HTML**

```
<foo>
    <bar>some text</bar>
</foo>
```

**XSL**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:template match="bar">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<bar>some text</bar>
```